# Show Background Apps/Services

Tags: applications, adb, root-access, background-process

I want to monitor apps/services running in background on my phone. I have searched online but I can't find any way to do so.

- There is no 'Running Services' option in Developer Settings or Apps section in MIUI.
- I have tried `adb shell top` command but the output is not much helpful. And I can't keep my phone connected to my PC at all times.

My phone is rooted. It's running on `MIUI 13 - Android 12`.

Please help.

Edit:
I want something similar to the 'Running Services' option in Developer Settings. (It's not available on Xiaomi devices)
[image]

Comment: [How to view background apps running on Android?](https://mirfatif.github.io/IAnswers/view_android_background_apps). Disclaimer: this link belongs to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check 'Running Services' by calling through ADB or on-device terminals like Termux, etc.

To use in the terminal, you need superuser access & remove the `adb shell` prefix.

ADB:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings -e :settings:show_fragment com.android.settings.applications.RunningServices
```

On-device terminal:

```
su
am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings -e :settings:show_fragment com.android.settings.applications.RunningServices
```